# Sharepoint Document Library one to many relationship

Tags: sharepoint

I am build a sharepoint document list that will be queried by a 3rd party app we are building.

The document list will hold around 5-10k documents.  I need to tag each document with a related customer ID's (we have thousands of customers).  Multiple customers will be tagged against a single document.

I will be querying the document list via sharepoint url to return documents based on customer ID in custom view.

What is the best way to create a one to many relationship between a document and multiple references/ID's?

Answer (score 0):

@user15092184,

You can create a list for the customers, then add a multiple-value lookup column to the document library and references the customer lists.

you can select 'Allow multiple values' to create a one to many relationship.

- https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-create-a-lookup-column-in-sharepoint/

BR

Comment: would that scale to 100k+ customer records?